# grouping lines from a file with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

In Python, I want to search through a file and output all the lines which contain a certain pattern.

I have used:

```
re.findall('5555',f.read())
```

so far, but this just gives me a list of all the matches, which is obviously not what I need. What do I need to use so that I get an output of all the lines that contain the pattern? i.e.:

```
blah.blah.5555.com
blah 5555 blah blah
5555 3452 1244
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you're on linux you can use this command : `cat filename | grep 5555`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, that qualifies for the [Useless use of cat award  :-)](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
re.findall('.*5555.*',f.read())
```

should do. Or with a [lazy operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
re.findall('.*?5555.*',f.read())
```

(Or maybe faster:

```
re.findall('(?:[^5]|5(?!555))*5555.*', f.read())
```

maybe even faster, with a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html):

```
re.findall('(?:[^5]|5(?!555))*+5555.*', f.read())
```

)

Answer (score 1):

I think this gonna work

```
lines = []
for line in f.readlines():
    match = re.findall('5555', line)
    if match:
        lines.append(line)

print "".join(lines)
```

also with only functional operator

```
print "".join(filter(lambda x: re.findall('5555',x), f.readlines()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a fixed string (your example seems to suggest you are), you may not even need regular expressions:

```
>>> with open('file.txt') as f:
...     x = [line for line in f if '5555' in line]
...
>>> print x
['blah.blah.5555.com\n', 'blah 5555 blah blah\n', '5555 3452 1244\n']
```